# Counting Quantities Instead of Number of Rows - MySQL/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, count, inner-join

I've asked a question regarding my SQL Query a while back and it worked fine until I noticed I had forgotten a very important piece to the code and now I've spent about an hour and a half trying to modify my code. The original question asked a good way to inner join two tables (orders and order_items). I then did a mysql_num_row() over the SQL Query and called it a day. I forgot that there's a cell in my order_items table named quantity. I need to integrate this into my count. I'm including my code below, and any ideas on how to easily implement this would be appreciated.

```
$SQL2ORDERSEARCH = "
SELECT * FROM order_items
INNER JOIN orders
ON orders.id = order_items.ord
WHERE orders.session = '$sessionID'
AND order_items.dish = '$SEARCHITEMS_OBJECT->dish'
AND order_items.size = 'full'";

$ORDERSEARCH = mysql_query($SQL2ORDERSEARCH) or die(mysql_error());
$ORDERSEARCH_NUM_ROWS = mysql_num_rows($ORDERSEARCH);
$FULLTOTAL = $FULLTOTAL + $ORDERSEARCH_NUM_ROWS;
```

I tried attempting a different route by doing a count. So I modified my Query as such:

```
$SQL2ORDERSEARCH = "
SELECT COUNT(quantity) FROM order_items
INNER JOIN orders
ON orders.id = order_items.ord
WHERE orders.session = '$sessionID'
AND order_items.dish = '$SEARCHITEMS_OBJECT->dish'
AND order_items.size = 'full'";
```

I don't technically need anything else since all I am trying to do is count how many dishes are involved here. I then created an if statement to figure if there was any rows coming from this query, and then calculate the quantity of them.

```
if($ORDERSEARCH_NUM_ROWS > 0 ) {
   while($ORDERSEARCH_OBJECT = mysql_fetch_object($ORDERSEARCH)) {
      $FULLQTY = COUNT($ORDERSEARCH_OBJECT->quantity);
   }
}
```

I've gotten mixed results. Sometimes I get just straight 1's down the data table. Other times (depending on any small changes such as $FULLQTY += COUNT($ORDERSEARCH_OBJECT->quantity); and trying that) I get results where it seems almost pattern-like with the numbers increasing by 5+ and somehow adding up to near 20+ the further down the list you go.

I'm just looking for an easy way to get the count of the quantity cell in order_items, displaying them down a table, and then calculating a total. I have everything fine and dandy minus getting the count of the quantity cell in order_items. Any ideas, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: After working on still, I used SUM() but had to set it up as SELECT SUM(quantity) AS quantityTotal in my query. Helpful to know to use SUM() but unhelpful in every single other way. Not upvoting anybody for their answers in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't a simple *select sum(quantity)* work here ?

Comment: When I attempted the SUM(quantity), I received either blank results or 1's across the board. I know there are more than one of each item in my results, so I know I'm not getting the correct results. Excuse me for being rather slow at this since I'm not the best at much with SQL beyond basic selects/inserts/updates/deletes.

Comment: After working on still, I used SUM() but had to set it up as SELECT SUM(quantity) AS quantityTotal in my query. Helpful to know to use SUM() but unhelpful in every single other way. Not upvoting anybody for their answers in this case.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your point : Sum was the way to go wasn't it ? What is it that was not helpful ? If our answers didn't help you, then please add an answer of your own with what you did to resolve the problem and mark it as the answer.